# Lucene won't return Sitecore results using LocationIDs or WildcardQuery

Tags: .net, lucene, sitecore

I’m currently having some trouble getting Lucene to return results filtered by a parent node in Sitecore. I am developing some custom components that display Lucene documents contextually based on what node is specified as the 'root' node to search from.

The 2 ways I’ve attempted to solve this are as follows:

- Setting the `LocationIDs` property of the `Param` object, as shown on this URL: http://firebreaksice.com/sitecore-search-by-site-with-the-advanced-database-crawler/

Unfortunately, it did not do what it claimed for me. It seems to ignore the property altogether and just returned the results with no parent item filter.

- Using a `WildcardQuery`:

  `queries.Add(new WildcardQuery(new Term("_sitecorefullpath", ContentFullPathRoot + "*")));`

To accomplish myI’ve done is store each Sitecore item's full content path (such as `/sitecore/content/Sites/Kauffman_org/Home/test/Events`) onto its corresponding Lucene document.
What I have (obviously incorrectly) assumed is that this line, which will generate a query with that path + an asterick wildcard at the end so it would match any child nodes, would actually perform a wildcard query and get me the results I want.

I've tested a wildcard query in Luke and it worked as expected. This URL shows what I'm talking about: https://i.stack.imgur.com/caQ1a.jpg

What gives? I can't figure out for the life of me why my WildcardQuery won't work... or why LocationIDs won't work. I need either of them to finish what I'm trying to accomplish. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Check your casing. Depending on how you "fire off" your query to Lucene, you might experience that your queries are being rewritten in ways you might not expect. For an example, see [TermQuery not returning on a known search term, but WildcardQuery does](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9431114/termquery-not-returning-on-a-known-search-term-but-wildcardquery-does?rq=1)

In Lucene terms, what you really want to be doing is probably a PrefixQuery, not a WildcardQuery - the performance difference would only be minor though, I expect.

Other than this; here's a few ideas to what might be going wrong:

1) Your Luke screenshot shows; you are using the "KeywordAnalyzer" for your query. While I can't remember all the analyzers off hand; it is likely that this one will break your query into tokens on every '/' character. This could produce unexpected results.

2) Make sure your path is stored as NOT_ANALYZED / UN_TOKENIZED - or Lucene will break up your path into segments; again splitting on '/'.

I do believe 2) is what might be happening to you. Lucene has tokenized your indexed field values, and Luke is able to perform searches against this index - but only using the KeywordAnalyzer (which in turn, also tokenises your query).

In short; if you can; store the path in a lowercased un-tokenized/not-analyzed field in the index; and query against it using a native Lucene PrefixQuery; alternatively a WildcardQuery.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on sitecore 6.6 and using advance database crawler, Please use below function to get skinnyitem result list based on location ID:

```
public static List<SkinnyItem> GetSkinnyItemsByLocationID(string indexName, string locationID, string templateID) {
            List<SkinnyItem> results = new List<SkinnyItem>();
            string language = Sitecore.Context.Language.Name;

            var searchParam = new SearchParam {
                Language = language,
                LocationIds = locationID,
                TemplateIds = templateID

            };

            using (var runner = new QueryRunner(indexName)) {
                return runner.GetItems(searchParam);
            }
        }
```